# Nilpotent elements of a non-commutative ring with trivial automorphism group form an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a non-commutative ring with identity such that the identity map is the only ring automorphism of $R$. Prove that the set $N$ of all nilpotent elements of $R$ is an ideal of $R$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a non-commutative ring that satisfies the hypothesis?  I can't think of one.  At a minimum, all invertible elements have to be central (else you have nontrivial inner automorphisms), which is kind of a weird condition.  Matrix rings obviously don't work, neither do (integral) group rings since they're generated by the group elements which are invertible, and "free non-commutative" rings on > 1 generator have automorphisms that permute the generators.  I'm running out of ideas for non-commutative rings.

Answer (score 10):

Hints:

1. In such a ring, every invertible element is central, else there is a nontrivial inner automorphism.
2. If $x$ is nilpotent, then $1-x$ is invertible.